# Flexbox children rendering wrong in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have the following HTML and css that works great in Firefox and Chrome to create a 3-column grid of boxes. But, in Safari it takes all the boxes and puts them into 1 row, squishing the width of each one so it will fit instead of allowing the float to push the boxes to a new line.

How can I get it to looks the same in Safari, any ideas?
(note: the html class '.box' is in a loop that dynamically generates boxes based on user input, so the number of boxes is variable)

HTML:

```
<div id="home-grid">
<div class="box">
Contents of box
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#home-grid {
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: -webkit-box;   /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
    display: -moz-box;      /* OLD: Firefox (buggy) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;   /* MID: IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;  /* NEW, Chrome 21–28, Safari 6.1+ */
    display: flex;          /* NEW: IE11, Chrome 29+, Opera 12.1+, Firefox 22+ */
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%
    }
#home-grid .box {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 192px!important;
        height: 180px;
        border: 1px solid #F73987;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work in the latest version of Safari by adding these two lines:

```
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
```

[see jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkpg8s38/1/)

Just to clarify, Safari still needs the `-webkit` prefix, according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark this answer, must have forgotten to do it last year!